# Selecting columns from a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datagridview

I want to be able to select the columns that are displayed in my DataGridView. I.e., I have a linq query that returns an IEnumerable but I don't want to display all the properties of Policy - I want to allow the user to choose what to display. So I thought something like this might work to create a "narrower" object with only the columns I want.

```
IEnumerable<Policy> policies = repository.GetPolicies();
var results = from p in policies select new {
    if (userPicked("PropertyOne")) PropertyOne = p.PropertyOne,
    if (userPicked("PropertyTwo")) PropertyTwo = p.PropertyTwo,
    ...
};
dataGridView1.DataSource = results;
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Part 2:
Why does this work:

```
IEnumerable<Policy> policies = repository.GetPolicies();
dataGridView1.DataSource = policies;
```

but this doesn't:

```
IEnumerable<Policy> policies = repository.GetPolicies();
var results = from p in policies select p;
dataGridView1.DataSource = results;
```

In the second case nothing is displayed in the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) if you need to select fields dynamically.  It contains a `Select` extension method that accepts a string of fields, so you can decide which fields to select at runtime:

```
public static IQueryable Select(this IQueryable source,    
       string selector, params object[] values);
```

Example of usage:

```
var products = db.Products
    .Where(condition)
    .OrderBy("Name")
    .Select(" new (ItemId,Name,Model,onsale)");
```

Part 2:  Your grid is expecting a bindable interface such as `IList`, but the second code example returns an `IQueryable`.  You can convert it to an `IList` by calling `ToList()`.

```
var results = (from p in policies select p).ToList();
```